# Change size of value valuebox in dashboard Quarto

Tags: r, shinydashboard, quarto

I'm creating a dashboard using `Quarto`. I would like to use [`valueboxes`](https://quarto.org/docs/dashboards/data-display.html#value-boxes) to show a value. The problem is that I don't know how to change the size of the value in a valuebox. In the example below you will see that it is out of the boundaries when the number is too big like this:

````
---
title: "How to change the value size of a valuebox"
format: dashboard
---

# {.sidebar}

Example code

# Tab

## Row {height="20%"}

```{r}
#| content: valuebox
#| title: "Example"

list(
  icon = "people",
  color = "primary",
  value = 123456789
)
```

```{r}
#| content: valuebox
#| title: "Example"

list(
  icon = "people",
  color = "primary",
  value = 123456789
)
```

## Row {height="80%"}
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see it doesn't fit the valuebox. I tried to use a `size` argument but that doesn't work for this. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to change the size of the value in a valuebox?

Comment: I consider this is a good question. You can maybe put it directly in the Issues section of the project in Github: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues Of course, you have to select the option Issues --> Question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing font size of valuebox values are defined as,

```css
.quarto-dashboard .bslib-value-box .value-box-value {
    font-size: clamp(.1em, 15cqw, 5em);
}
```

And from the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp),

> The `clamp()` CSS function clamps a middle value within a range of values between a defined minimum bound and a maximum bound. The function takes three parameters: a minimum value, a preferred value, and a maximum allowed value.

So to change the font size of the valuebox's values you can change the preferred value or even change the min or max values of the `clamp()` function.

For example, putting the following in a `style.css` file,

```css
.quarto-dashboard .bslib-value-box .value-box-value {
    font-size: clamp(.1em, 10cqw, 5em) !important;
}
```

renders to,

[image]